# /ui-api/layout/ doesn't return all fields

Tags: api, page-layout

For some reason REST API method
/services/data/v53.0/ui-api/layout/Account doesn't return all sections and fields. For other objects it seems to work ok.

Please help

upd: user see one layout at SF site, API returns other.

Comment: Maybe check permissions for the user?

Comment: Do you have custom recordtypes on Account? If you do, then the issue is probably that your _default_ layout doesn't contain those things and you need to supply the recordtypeId in the query string.

Comment: Also, could this be impacted by permissions?

Comment: Thanks! I guess, user has custom record types.

/services/data/v{{version}}/sobjects/:SOBJECT_API_NAME/describe response contains recordTypeInfos object, where I can choose 'master' record type id, and add it to query string. 
But I am still not sure that master record Id is needed. Perhaps it's required to detect  other recordType Id.